# jQuery get html id from selected dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

As i have multiple drop-downs in my form, I would like to retrieve the HTML id from one of the selected drop-downs. I have the following code for my drop-downs on change:

```
$("select[name$='product_type']").change(function(){}
```

when using `console.log($(this).select());`

i can see the selected drop-down id in the console;

[image]

What is the syntax for retrieving this id into a var?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `$(this).attr("id")` to get the id.

You can also use `this.id` (as already mentioned in the comments). I just found a [performance test](http://jsperf.com/browser-diet-this-attr-id-vs-this-id) for `$(this).attr("id")` vs. `this.id` with the result of `this.id` being faster, which is expected as it's pure javascript instead of a javascript library like jQuery.

Comment: `this.id` will also work.

Comment: works, ty, will accept as soon as i can (10 min window)

Answer (score 1):

You just take `id` property:

```
$("select[name$='product_type']").change(function() {
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score -2):

`$("select[name$='product_type'] option:selected").attr("id");` inside the change callback.